# I don't understand the solution to this geometric problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> The figure shows a circle with $AB$ as a diameter.
>
> [image]
>
> Given that $\angle{ADE} = \angle{DCA}$ and $\angle{CBA} = 70^\circ$, find
>
> 1. $\angle{FEB}$
> 2. $\angle{EFC}$

I could not solve this question and I do not understand the answer:

> 1. \begin{align}
>    \text{Let } \angle{ADE} &= \angle{DCA} = x^\circ \\
>    \angle{ACB} &= 90^\circ \color{grey}{ \text{(rt. } \angle \text{ in a semicircle)} } \\
>    \angle{DAE} &= 180^\circ - 90^\circ - x^\circ \color{grey}{(\angle \text{ sum of a } \triangle) } \\
>    &= (90 - x)^\circ \\
>    \angle{FEB} &= (90 - x)^\circ + x^\circ \color{grey}{ \text{ext. } \angle = \text{ sum of int. opp. } \angle{s} } \\
>    &= 90^\circ
>    \end{align}

> 2. \begin{align}
>    \angle{EFC} &= 360^\circ - 90^\circ - 90^\circ - 70^\circ \\
>    &= 110^\circ
>    \end{align}

In **1**, I do not understand the line $\angle{DAE} = 180^\circ - 90^\circ - x^\circ$. Where does $90^\circ$ come from?

Comment: FEB is from the sum of angles in triangle DAE. On the other hand the preceding DAE is because ADCB is inscribed.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I understood that, I wrote that by mistake. I don't understand how $\angle{DAE}$ is calculated...

Comment: Because DCB=90+x and opposite angles of inscribed quadrilateral add up to 180.

Comment: I believe it is implied that $AED$ is 90 degrees. They do not explicitly state it -- but they should have!

Comment: @CharlieS I don't think it was implied, otherwise we would calculate $\angle{FEB}$ simply by subtracting $\angle{AED}$ from $180^\circ$. It turns out that $\angle{FEB}$ was $90^\circ$ anyhow, hence $\angle{AED} = 90^\circ$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral

$$\angle DAB + \angle DCB =180$$

$$\angle DAE = 180-\angle DCB = 180 - (90+x)= 90 -x$$

(opposite angles of cyclic quadrilateral are supplementary)

$$\angle FEB =\angle DEB = \angle ADE +\angle DAE=x+(90-x)=90$$

(exterior angle of $\triangle DEB$)